# CKError code: 12, No operations present in request

Tags: cloudkit

I keep seeing this error when performing a query in CloudKit. Here is the code that usually sets it off:

```
if (self.userID) {

    CKReference *referenceToUser = [[CKReference alloc]initWithRecordID:self.userID action:CKReferenceActionDeleteSelf];
    NSPredicate *userSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"User", referenceToUser];
    CKQuery *findHoneymoon = [[CKQuery alloc]initWithRecordType:@"Honeymoon" predicate:userSearch];
    CKQueryOperation *findHMOp = [[CKQueryOperation alloc]initWithQuery:findHoneymoon];
    findHMOp.resultsLimit = 1;

    __block CKRecord *userHoneyMoon;
    findHMOp.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record){
        userHoneyMoon = record;
        self.userHoneymoon.honeymoonID = record.recordID;
    };

    __block BOOL errorOccured = NO;
    findHMOp.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *operationError){

        if (operationError)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error searching for user honeymoon, description: %@, and code: %lu, and heck, heres the domain: %@", operationError.localizedDescription, operationError.code, operationError.domain);

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"HoneymoonError" object:nil];

            errorOccured = YES;
        }

        if (!userHoneyMoon && !errorOccured)
        {
            [self createBlankHoneymoon];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.userHoneymoon populateHoneymoonImages];
        }
    };

    [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] addOperation:findHMOp];
}
```

What's really vexing is that this error only occurs about 1 in 5 times I try to run the program.

Here is what gets logged when the error occurs:

> Error searching for user honeymoon, description: No operations present in request, and code: 12, and heck, heres the domain: CKErrorDomain

As you can see from the code there ARE operations in the request, does anyone know any other reason this error might occur and how to handle it?

Comment: Update your question with the complete output of your `NSLog` line for the error.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I made that edit

Comment: Hi @SamuelBoyce, did you find any solution for that

Comment: Hey @MaheshPrasadMahalik, I never did. My recommendation would honestly be to use something other than CloudKit. I know that's not super helpful.